# "Missing ) after argument list." in apps script

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I copied a working formula fill-down from a different sheet, swapped out the relevant cells/formula for the new sheet, and now am getting an error message (missing ) after argument) on line 3. (sorry if this is super obvious, I'm VERY new to scripts)

I tried substituting a very simple mathematical formula instead of the one I want to use, and that didn't throw the error code, so it has something to do with my formula.

orginal:

```
function myFunction() { 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); ss.getRange("E3").setFormula("=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(F3:BS3,MAX(IF(F3:BS3>0,COLUMN($A1:$BS1),0)))), 1, 1)");

var lr = ss.getLastRow();
var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(3, 5, lr-2);
ss.getRange("E3").copyTo(fillDownRange);
```

not working:

```
function myFunction() {   
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
ss.getRange("D4").setFormula("=CONCATENATE(B4," ",C4)");

var lr = ss.getLastRow();
var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(4,4, lr-2);
ss.getRange("D4").copyTo(fillDownRange);
```

Answer (score 2):

It reads the second " as a closing " and thus it's missing the ) in the first part. The third " gets handled as a new opening ".

You need to either escape the pair of ".
`ss.getRange("D4").setFormula("=CONCATENATE(B4,\" \",C4)");`

Or you could try Using different " like ', if Google App-Scripts supports those.
`ss.getRange("D4").setFormula('=CONCATENATE(B4," ",C4)');`

Comment: I can confirm Google Apps Script does support using single-quotes. They're actually [recommended here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Strings#Strings) over double-quotes since they can interfere with HTML and as you've seen above, it's not just HTML they can interfere with.